# Find words between brackets in a sentence with some constraints (inner brackets) regex

Tags: c++, regex

I have a the following sentence:

```
[[Image:Levellers declaration and standard.gif|thumb|200px|Woodcut from a [[Diggers]] document by william everard]]
```

---

## Regular expression

I am using the following regular expression in order to extract the words that are between brackets **[[ ]]**:

```
regex = "\\[\\[(.*?)\\]\\]"
```

The output should be equal to the following sentence:

```
Image:Levellers declaration and standard.gif|thumb|200px|Woodcut from a [[Diggers]] document by william everard
```

I want to only take into consideration the left-most brackets **]]**

---

### Problem

**regex** will extract `[[Image:Levellers declaration and standard.gif|thumb|200px|Woodcut from a [[Diggers]]` and will leave `document by william everard]]`.

---

## Question

How can I ignore the inner brackets represented by **]]**.

---

### Update V0

I wrote a simple program inspired by [BalancedParentheses.cpp](https://gist.github.com/mycodeschool/7207410) in order to locate the **beginning** and **ending** of the text between brackets in  a string.

---

### Source code

```
    #include <stack>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    
    using namespace std;
    bool AreParanthesesBalanced(string exp)
    { 
        stack<char>  S;
        vector<pair<int, int>> index;
        int end;
        vector<int> start;
        for(int i = 0; i < exp.length(); i++)
        {
           if(exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '{' || exp[i] == '[')
           {
             S.push(exp[i]);
             start.push_back(i);
            }
                    
            else if(exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == '}' || exp[i] == ']')
            {
                if(S.empty() || !ArePair(S.top(),exp[i]))
                {
                  return false;
                }
                  
               else
               {
                 S.pop();
                 end = i;
                 index.push_back(make_pair(start[start.size() - 1] ,end));
                 start.pop_back();
               }      
            }
         }
                
         for(int i = 0; i < index.size(); i ++)
         {
            cout << index[i].first <<"  "<< index[i].second << endl;
         }
       return S.empty() ? true:false;
   }
        
        int main()
        {
          string exp = "[[Image:Levellers declaration and standard.gif|thumb|200px|Woodcut from a [[Diggers]] document by william everard]] ";
        
           bool x = reParanthesesBalanced(exp);
           return 0;
        }
```

---

### Output

```
75  83
74  84
1  113
0  114
```

Comment: C++ regex can't do bracket balancing. Write a parser instead, or use an engine that can balance bracket, like PCRE.

Comment: Try "\\[\\[(.*?)\\]\\]$"

Comment: @fro: That will fail on a long wiki (?) document.

Comment: You are in not greedy mode, so stop at the first `]]`, you may remove the `?` to stop at the last.

Comment: [OT]: it is a good place to use raw string: `R"\[\[(.*?)\]\]"`.

Comment: @nhahtdh thats correct! :)

Comment: If there's not deeper nesting try with a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `"\\[\\[((?:(?!\\[\\[|\\]\\]).|\\[\\[.*?\\]\\])*)\\]\\]"` See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oQ9jG2/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that you use a lazy (`*?`) quantifier, instead of a greedy (`*`) one.

The lazy quantifier will stop as soon as it meets the first `]]` in the string, even if it is not the final one.

You can simply modify your regex to this :

```
regex = "\\[\\[(.*)\\]\\]"
```

Comment: If it were that simple, it would suffice to trim the leading and trailing `[`s and `]`s.

Comment: @Theox So I will prevent the regular expression from exiting when it meets the first ]].

Comment: @HaniGoc: On string with 2 of these on one line, you will get only one of them. This solution is broken.

Comment: yes you are right @nhahtdh. well my mistake i didn't ask the question correctly. you are absolutly right. By using the PCRE library will I be able to solve this problem?

Comment: I think @nhahtdh this link will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets

Comment: @HaniGoc: It should be possible. You should look up questions on bracket balancing in PHP to see how to write such pattern.